# (Document type: Appointment, Operation: create) ERROR

Tags: odoo-12

If i create new record with diffrerent user(limited access) this prompt error will show. Why?.

I already declare user_1 in security (csv).

```
access_emergency_nurse,Emergency Nurse,model_hms_appointment,acs_hms.user_1,1,1,1,0
```

Comment: Can you post the log?

Answer (score 1):

This is error occured due to record rule i think you define record rule for this model and that is causing problem.Thanks

Comment: what do you mean?
This is my record rule with the model of hms.appointment.

<record id="hms_appointment_patient_rule" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">All Appointment Rule</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_hms_appointment"/>
            <field name="global" eval="True"/>
            <field name="domain_force">[(1,'=',1)]</field>
            <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('acs_hms.group_hms_manager'))]"/>
        </record>

Comment: I check record rules and i found out that the groups i supposed to be to used is not declare in record rules. Thanks